# How to load only used Font Awesome icons in a Vue 3 project?

Tags: vuejs3, font-awesome

In my Vue 3 project I need to use some Font Awesome icons, but not all obviously. But if I load icons as webfont, it loads all informations of all icons.

If I use icons as SVG I lost the benefit using icons as font. For example: adjust to font size, color, etc.

In Angular I can use `<fa-icon ...>` tag to use icons like this.

How can I load only used icons but still keep font-behavior benefits?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [@unocss/preset-icons](https://github.com/unocss/unocss/tree/main/packages/preset-icons) it will do it automatically for you and you will gain access to a [bunch of other icons](https://icones.netlify.app/) as well.

The CSS it uses for the icons is different, they are not used like font, but one may still change their color & size by setting the corresponding font properties. Check [this post](https://antfu.me/posts/journey-with-icons-continues) for more info.

Comment: Good stuff, but in this case I must use Font Awesome iconset. Must be adapted the visual design. So I can't change it.

Comment: Which Font Awesome iconset. You will have access to a few of its collections like: [Font Awesome 5 Regular - 151 icons](https://icones.netlify.app/collection/fa-regular?s=) & [FA5 Solid - 1001 icons](https://icones.netlify.app/collection/fa-solid?s=)

Comment: For example Font Awesome 5 Regular. But I feel this question is irrelevant, because I use webpack with FA npm package and with any iconset... hippotetitcly I want to use fab-facebook, far-save, fal-trash icons only. I'm looking for solution for this scenario.

Comment: I see, maybe try this then https://github.com/patrickhulce/fontmin-webpack